# Does publishing in journals known as "predatory" hurt one's reputation?

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers, reputation

Does publishing in what is known as a "predatory" (such as OMICS) journal diminish ones reputation? Do these publications help at all when applying for grants (or do they impede ones chance)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, your reputation is diminished, because people will think you couldn't get published any other way.  It will actively harm your chances at pretty much any interaction with reputable organizations, including grant proposals.  Don't do it.

Comment: (One of my pet peeves.) Publications can harm only *passively*. I guess you said *actively* to mean *seriously* / *heavily* / *strongly*; it's unlikely that any *actions* will be taken by the publication.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: No, "actively" is the right word here. What jakebeal's sentence means is that publishing in a predatory journal will not merely fail to help one's chances, and not merely take effort away from things that will help one's chances; but rather, that it in itself will harm one's chances. This doesn't necessarily imply anything about the strength of the harm (except that it is enough to be worth mentioning). (If it makes you feel better, the "it" here refers to *publishing*, not *publications*. And publishing certainly *is* an action.)