# Possibly, quick acceptance for publication

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers

Two days ago, a physics journal received my manuscript and today they informed me that the editor and reviewer accepted my manuscript for publication. this is the first time for me publishing a manuscript, but two days, isn't that quick?
and they told me that I will pay around 700 Euros for the first installment.
I really need your advice here, I am afraid of getting screwed.

Comment: Is your paper about COVID19 or something? Otherwise, this is a red flag. Is this a reputable journal?

Comment: They sound legit and they have many publication on their site. this is their website tsijournals.com/journals/journal-of-physics-astronomy.html –

Comment: In my research vicinity, people very rarely pay to publish their papers. What about yours?

Comment: Trade Science Inc. (the publisher) is generally considered predatory and disreputable. See [here](https://beallslist.net/) and [here](https://predatoryjournals.com/publishers/). I wouldn't publish with them - especially not with such quick acceptance.

Comment: is there a different value in publishing in a predatory journal or a normal journal?, like does it affect the published manuscript

Comment: @shivansirdy Yes, of course. Articles don't go through proper quality assurance and make you look bad for not avoiding a predatory journal

Comment: @shivansirdy There are many questions about predatory journals on the site already. Maybe you should take a look at [What are “fake”, “shady”, and/or “predatory” journals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17379/17254) and [Does publishing in journals known as “predatory” hurt one's reputation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49746/17254).

Comment: Thank you dears for the inputs, much appreciated

Comment: Thoughts from my less than 2 minute investigation, most of which was spent waiting on slow website responses: (1) The journal's title is ridiculously general, so much so that it looks like a parody for titles of predatory journals. (2) Clicking on a random volume, 6, and random issue number, 2, I then randomly selected [this paper](https://www.tsijournals.com/articles/accelerating-universe-explained.pdf), and even though I know next to nothing about this topic, the sophomoric level of math, physics, and logical reasoning is unmistakable. For what it's worth, this paper took 8 days to review.

Comment: Don't pay any money!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if I submitted an article to a predatory journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26455/what-should-i-do-if-i-submitted-an-article-to-a-predatory-journal)

Comment: Duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs

Answer (score 4):

It is very unusual for a paper to be reviewed and get accepted in two days. Of course, there are some exceptions such as:

1. Solution to a very well known and long studied problem (even in this case, it is highly unlikely for the review process to be completed in 2 days).
2. Dramatically improving the conditions of a current crisis (e.g. a vaccine for COVID-19 outbreak)
3. Very short [image: Such as this one]

Other than these extreme cases, I, personally would not choose to publish in that journal, let alone **pay** for the publication.

Also, you can check [this famous list](https://clinicallibrarian.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/bealls-list-of-predatory-publishers/) for future considerations.

Comment: I think you have a stray "not" in the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated